# jqgrid: I would like to auto select the cell my mouse is currently hovering over

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, hover, mouse

I know this may be an odd question.  How do I auto select the cell in jqgrid that my mouse is currently hovering over?  The reason for this is, I am not exactly sure how to accomplish my custom deletion of a row without the cell being selected first.

Currently I have:

jqgrid code snippet:

```
gridComplete: function(){
    var ids = jQuery("#breed_list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++)
    { 
        var cl = ids[i];
        ed = "<img src=\"../images/edit.png\" alt=\"Edit\" onclick=\"jQuery('#breed_list').editRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
        de = "<img class=\"del_row\" src=\"../images/delete.png\" alt=\"Delete\" />";
        ce = "<input class=\"del_row\" type='button' onclick=\"deleteRow()\" />"; 
        jQuery("#breed_list").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:ed+de+ce}); 
    }
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        //do code
    });
},
```

**Problem:**
The function will NOT execute when I click the button without the cell selected.  If I select the cell then click the button the deleteRow() function will execute.

**Possible Solution?:**
The idea is to auto select the cell my mouse is currenAtly hovering for when the user does click the button the function will execute properly.  All other ideas are welcome :-)

***EDIT***
**Working Code:**
The idea of auto select the cell was rather simple with jQuery.

code:

```
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        var valId = $(".ui-state-hover").attr("id");
        jQuery("#breed_list").setSelection(valId, false);
        //alert(valId);
    });
```

-Rich

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself you should add your own answer and mark his own answer as "accepted". In the way your question will disappear from [the list of unanswered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50). About one day you could be need to wait till your could mark your own answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Code:**
The idea of auto select the cell was rather simple with jQuery.

code:

```
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        var valId = $(".ui-state-hover").attr("id");
        jQuery("#breed_list").setSelection(valId, false);
        //alert(valId);
    });
```